# Electron App - How to Host Another Program Inside a div Element?

Tags: node.js, electron, desktop-application, child-process, window-handles

I want to host existing application on my machine inside an Electron app. For example, I want to run Mozzila Firefox inside a div element.

In WPF and Windows Forms I managed to host anoher .exe file by setting Windows Handle in a Panel element from Windows Forms. Is there a similar way to do that in Electron?

I managed to open external application in it's own window with this code:

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile;
var executablePath = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
var ch = child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(data.toString());
});
console.log(ch);
```

When I read the console log, I saw that child element also has `_handle` value, I'm not sure if that's something similar to window handle.

Comment: I would say, the question has nothing to do with Electron itself. The correct question to ask is "how do you run an external program in a DIV in a webpage". I don't think there is an easy response to this.